# How subViewA change the param on subviewB?

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, selector

I created [two views in Main.storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMugj.png) with

```
class ViewController: UIViewController 
{
   var cardsOnTableCounts = 0
   @IBOutlet weak var headStackView: HeadStackView!
   @IBOutlet weak var gridCardView: GridView!

   @objc func touchDeal3Card () 
   {
    gridCardView.cellCounts += 3
   }
}
```

I created a button in class HeadStackView

```
class HeadStackView: UIView 
{
  var deal3Card: UIButton = UIButton.init()

  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    setDeal3Card()
  }

  private func setDeal3Card () {
    let leftButtonFrame : CGRect = CGRect(x: bounds.maxX/15, y: bounds.maxY/6, width: bounds.maxX/3, height: bounds.maxY*0.7)
    deal3Card = UIButton.init(frame: leftButtonFrame)
    deal3Card.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
    deal3Card.setTitle("Deal 3 Cards", for: .normal)
    deal3Card.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.touchDeal3Card), for: .touchUpInside)
    addSubview(deal3Card)
}
```

In GridView.swift

```
class GridView: UIView 
{
  var cellCount: Int = 5 {didSet { setNeedsDisplay(); setNeedsLayout()}}

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    drawGrid() // it draws cellCount of cells
  }
}
```

My goal is when the UIButton deal3Card is pressed, gridCardView will redraw itself with more cards on gridCardView.

The code above passed compiler and show the button (deal3card). but when I click on button, it gets exception:

> 2018-10-23 19:52:54.283032+0200 gridTest[23636:5175258]
>   -[gridTest.HeadStackView touchDeal3Card]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb97180c8f0
>
> 2018-10-23 19:52:54.287469+0200 gridTest[23636:5175258] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[gridTest.HeadStackView
>   touchDeal3Card]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7fb97180c8f0'

Comment: you keep referring to subviews so I am wondering if these are subviews on one main view in which case they are children for the same ViewController?

Comment: Yes. I created two views on storyboard. They are under the same viewcontroller but each has its own viewclass.

Comment: Your code is nonsense. Can’t tell the variable names from the class names. Why are you subclassing SubView1?

Comment: @matt sorry i miswrote some code here, have updated. Thanks to point out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proximate cause of the crash is this line:

```
deal3Card.addTarget(self, 
    action: #selector(ViewController.touchDeal3Card), for: .touchUpInside)
```

The target `self` is wrong. You want to send this message to the view controller, which implements `touchDeal3Card`. But in your code, `self` is the button, which doesn't.

The simplest solution, given the architecture you've constructed, is to replace `self` with `nil`. This will cause the `touchDeal3Card` to percolate up the responder chain and reach the view controller.

---

Having said *that*, I would suggest that the architecture itself is wrong. View controller should control views; views should not control themselves. The view controller, not the view, should be creating the button. This is well indicated by the fact that this code is totally wrong:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    setDeal3Card()
}
```

That is a total misuse of `draw` and is going to land you in terrible trouble. The only thing you should do in `draw` is (wait for it) draw. Adding subviews in `draw` is as wrong as anything could possibly be.

Comment: Thank you very much!!  It works now after I change self to ViewController() !

Comment: No, that's wrong too. Please read my whole answer, perhaps several times, perhaps out loud.